# Elementary connected proof

Tags: real-analysis

> If $C\subset \mathbb{R}^p$ is connected and $x$ is a cluster point of
>   $C$, then $C\cup\{x\}$ is connected.

My attempt:

I have been told the easiest way to prove disconnected/connected is by contradiction, so I am going to attempt that here.

Let $A,B$ be a disconnection for $D$, where $D =C\cup\{x\}$. Then we have that $A\cap D$ and $B\cap D$ are non-empty and have union $D$. Now suppose that $x\in A$, then $x\notin B\cap D$ since $A\cap D$ and $B\cap D$ are disjoint. And I get stuck and can't continue any further.

Comment: For my personal experience, the easiest way to show that a set $C$ is connected is by proving that every continuous function $f:C\to\{0,1\}$ is constant, where $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with the discrete topology (or metric, if you want). In your case you have $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, with $x_n\in C$, so if $f:C\cup\{x\}\to\{0,1\}$ is continuous, then all the values $f(x_n)$ are equal, so the same happens to $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Hmm, I don't think we have been taught that way. We haven't gotten into limits yet, it is still a couple of sections away.

Comment: Moreover, the reasoning above works with any set $D$ such that $C\subseteq D\subseteq\overline C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: What does the fact that $x$ is a cluster point tell you? (Every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects $C $). Also, for this separation, $A,B$  are open. Thus what can you conclude? Is there a way to separate ${x}$ from $C$ with open neighborhoods?

**LEMMA 6.7** Let $C$ and $D$ be subsets of a topological space $X$. Assume that $C$ is connected and $C\subseteq D$. Further assume that $U$ and $V$ form a separation of $D$ in $X$. Then either $C\subseteq U$ or $C\subseteq V.$

***Proof*.** Suppose that neither $C\subseteq U $ nor $C\subseteq V$. Then $U\cap C \ne \emptyset$ and $V\cap C \ne \emptyset. $ It follows that $U$ and $V$ form a separation of $C$ in $X$, contradicting the assumption that $C$ is connected.

**Note that in your problem $x \in CL(C)$**, because $CL(C) = C \cup C'$ where $C'$ is the set of limit points of $C$.

We have a theorem: 
**Theorem 6.8:** *Let C be connected in $X$, and assume that $C \subseteq A \subseteq CL(C)$. Then $A$ is connected in $X$*
***Proof*.** Suppose that $A$ is not connected in $X$, and let $U$ and $V$ form a separation of $A$ in $X$. Then either $C \subseteq U$ or $C \subseteq V$. WLOG assume that $C\subseteq U$. Thus $C\cap V = \emptyset$ . But, since $U$ and $V$ form a separation of $A$ in $X$, it follows that $A\cap V \ne \emptyset$. Pick $x\in A\cap V$. Now, $x\in A$ and $A \subseteq CL(C)$ imply $x\in CL(C).$ But $x\in V$, an open set in $X$ which is disjoint from $C$. So $x$ cannot be in the closure of $C$, yielding a contradiction. Thus it follows that $A$ is connected in $X$.

Therefore since $C\subset C\cup \{x\}\subseteq CL(C)$, $C\cup\{x\}$ is connected. 
References: Introduction to Topology Pure and Applied by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what it means to be a cluster point. And for your second question, since $A,B$ are open then there are points of $C$.

Comment: @Q.matin Yes, a cluster point is a specific type of limit point. Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $X$.  A point $x$ in $X$ _is a limit point of_ $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in a point other than $x$.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is an alternative, *positive*, approach: If $X$ is a *topological* space and $C\subseteq X$ is connected ($C\ne\emptyset$), then any set $D$ such that $C\subseteq D\subseteq\overline C$ is connected. Here $\overline C$, the *closure* of $C$ **in** $\boldsymbol{X}$, is defined as the intersection of all the closed subsets of $X$ containing $C$. In particular $\overline C$ is closed, and if $A,B$ are subsets of $X$ with $A\subseteq B$, then $\overline B$ is a closed set containing $A$, hence $\overline B\supseteq\overline A$.

Proof: Let $f:D\to\{0,1\}$ be continuous, where $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with the discrete topology; in particular both $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are closed sets, so their inverse images $f^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)$ and $f^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)$ are closed in $D$. Since $C$ is connected, we can suppose, for example, that $f=0$ on $C$. Thus, $C$ is contained in the closed set $f^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)$, so the closure of $C$ in $D$, namely $D$, is also contained in $f^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)$, and this shows that $f$ is constant on $D$, which shows connectedness of $D$.

(A minor clarification: if $F$ is a closed subset of $D$ containing $C$, then $F=D\cap H$, where $H$ is closed in $X$. Then  $C\subseteq H$, and so by definition we have $\overline C\subseteq H$, which implies of course $D\subseteq H$. Consequently we have $F=D$, which shows that the closure of $C$ in $D$ is precisely $D$.)

Comment: Thanks Mate, I like this proof.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

Suppose $U,V$ are open, disjoint and $C \cup \{x\} \subset U \cup V$. Without loss of generality, suppose $x \in U$. Since $x$ is an accumulation (cluster) point, some point of $C$ lies in $U$ also (this is the key point of the proof). Since $C$ is connected, we must have $C \subset U$. Hence $C \cup \{x\} \subset U$. It follows that $C \cup \{x\}$ is connected.

Comment: Why did you have the fact that $C \cup \{x\} \subset U \cup V$, would it still be right if you had $C \cup \{x\} \subset U$ and took out the $V$?

Comment: No. You need to show if $C \cup \{x\}$ is written as the union of two disjoint open sets, then it is contained entirely inside one of them. If the set was disconnected, then it could be written as the union of two disjoint open sets, **and** it would intersect both. The above proves that it cannot be done, hence is connected.

Comment: Understand now, thanks a lot !