# If a set $A$ is disconnected in $(X,d_1)$, then it is disconnected in $(X,d_2)$ for any metric $d_2\geq d_1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

If a set $A$ is disconnected in metric space $(X,d_1)$, then it is disconnected in $(X,d_2)$ for any metric $d_2\geq d_1$

we need to prove or disprove.

we think it is true.
any open set for $d_1$ is also open for $d_2$. so,if we are able to disconnect $A$ with open sets, we would be able to it with the same open sets.

Comment: Your thinking is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As I [said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521867/family-of-connected-sets-proving-union-is-connected/521886#521886) in several previous [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331804/elementary-connected-proof/331813#331813): since $(A,d_1)$ is disconnected, then there is a nonconstant continuous function $f:(A,d_1)\to\{0,1\}$, where $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with the discrete topology (or metric if you want). Since $d_2\geq d_1$ then the identity map $id:(A,d_2)\to(A,d_1)$ is continuous. Therefore the composite map $f\circ id:(A,d_2)\to\{0,1\}$ is nonconstant and continuous, so $(A,d_2)$ is disconnected as well. This argument works as well if you replace the metrics $d_i$ by topologies.